# python- how to select and show a plot from a multi-plot figure?

Tags: python

I have created a multi-plots figure, but I want to select and show the plot which has the smallest error as well, how should I do that?

```
figContour = plt.figure()
figContour.suptitle("Figure 3, Question 1(b): contour plots for various training sessions.")
Total_err = []
for i in range(9):

    X,t = datasets.make_moons(n_samples=200, noise=0.2)
    clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=[3],
                             activation='tanh',
                             solver='sgd',
                             learning_rate_init=0.01,
                             tol=10.0**(-20),
                             max_iter=10000)
    clf.fit(X,t)
    acc = clf.score(X,t)
    error = 1 - acc
    print ("Error: [%s]" % error)
    Total_err.append(error)

    ax1 = figContour.add_subplot(3,3,i+1)
    ax1.set_xlim(-6,6)
    ax1.set_ylim(-6,6)
    colors = np.array(["r","b"])
    ax1.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], color=colors[t],s=0.1)
    bonnerlib2.dfContour(clf,ax1)
plt.show()
smallest = np.argmin(Total_err)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to have both versions of the plot at the same time, you can create a list of axes, hide all but the selected one and use `change_geometry` to update its position:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3)
axes = axes.flatten()
metric = []

for i in range(9):
    dat = np.random.exponential(1, (10, 2))
    metric.append(dat.sum())

    axes[i].set_xlim(-6,6)
    axes[i].set_ylim(-6,6)
    axes[i].scatter(dat[:, 0], dat[:, 1])

_min = np.argmin(metric)

[axes[i].set_visible(False) for i, _ in enumerate(axes) if i != _min]
axes[_min].change_geometry(1,1,1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the point is I have to show both versions at same time

Comment: You could save the clf object and the data and replot it? Otherwise, there's some examples on this site for duplicating matplotlib axes but it rather difficult